# F5 key behaving as FN + F5

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

All of my laptop—a  Samsung Expert running Windows 10—f[number] keys are behaving now as if I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f[number]</kbd> shortcut.

For example, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> normally disables touchpad. Then, when I press <kbd>f5</kbd> key to refresh a page, my touchpad is disabled.

This started happening with a few days ago. How to revert this behavior to the normal (<kbd>f1</kbd> working as <kbd>f1</kbd>, <kbd>f2</kbd> working as <kbd>f2</kbd> etc…)?

Answer (score 2):

I feel stupid now. My Samsung Expert laptop has a <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> key (located after <kbd>f12</kbd>) to toggle this behavior. Just press it and things started working normally.

Not needed to going to BIOS and disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> always on function.

Comment: That's nice, however I knew about the fn lock, as my old  computer did have it, but the current one doesn't. Anyone knows how to change this behavior?